# Code acting like it is asynchronous when I don't think it is

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I'm struggling to see why some code is behaving as it is.

Vue3 front end login page interacting with Google Firebase services (authentication and firestore db)

```
const onSubmit = () => {
     .
     .
     .
     // above missing section just gathers some form data

     signInUser(form_email.value, form_passowrd.value)
          .then(() => {
               const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
               if (user.emailVerified) {
                    checkUser(user.uid)
                    router.push({ name: 'Profile' })
               }
               else {
                    resendVerification.value = true
                    commandNotification('show', 'error', 'Unverified Account')
               }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
               if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                    commandNotification('show', 'error', 'Invalid Email Address')
               }
               // followed by other checks
          })
}
```

signInUser is the official firebase auth email and password sign in function that is imported into this module.

So, user is signed in, then I check to see if the user has verified their email address. If they have I do some further checks in a "users" firebase table, and then route user to their profile page.

The problem that I am having is that the `router.push` is happening before the check user function has completed. I've even put a 10 second setTimeout between the two lines and the router push comes immediately.

It seems checkUser is running asynchronously but I didn't think it was. I've not marked it async myself.

The checkUser function itself does the following

```
const checkUser = (userid) => {
     db.collection("users").doc(userid).get()
     .then((d) => {
          if (d.exists) {
               userStateStore.action(MutationType.user.updateUser,
               {
                    id: d.data().id,
                    country: d.data().country,
                    handle: d.data().handle
               }
          }
          else {
               // user creation when they do not exist
          }
     })
}
```

I'm currently testing with a user that already exists. Because the route is being called immediately the profile data is not in the vuex store.

I'm looking for some pointers on how to approach debugging this, or an answer if you see a specific problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `get()` is a remote, async operation.  I think you do realize that, because the code calls .then() on the (promise) return value

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have an `onAuthStateChanged` listener? That maybe redirecting user after the user is logged in.

Comment: Thank you @danh this was the only hint I needed. I've added the push to the profile page into the then of checkUser (as Porter suggested) and I made a note to refactor later as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkUser *is* async. It should return the promise that `get()` returns...

```
const checkUser = (userid) => {
    return db.collection("users").doc(userid).get()
    // ...
```

I'd cleanup the caller (without async/await) like this...

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  return signInUser(form_email.value, form_passowrd.value)
      .then(() => {
         const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
         return user.emailVerified ? checkUser(user.uid) : Promise.resolve(false)
      }).then(checkUserResult => {
        if (checkUserResult) {
          router.push({ name: 'Profile' });
        } else {
          resendVerification.value = true
          commandNotification('show', 'error', 'Unverified Account')
        }
      })
      // ...
```

These could also be made tidier (and exactly equivalent) using async/await syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems checkUser is running asynchronously but I didn't think it was. I've not marked it async myself.

Yes, `.get()` is asynchronous and even though you haven't used `async/await` you're instead using [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

One solution could be to put the `router.push()` invocation within the callback of the `.then()` within `checkUser()`.